# Iterative Methods for Large Sparse Systems and The Conjugate Gradient Method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a rather difficult question (for me) that I can't quite figure out. I'll pose the problem and the context for it below.

> Verify the fact that $\alpha_i$$\frac{p_{i}^T p_i}{e_{i}^TAe_i}$ = $\frac{p_{i}^Tp_i}{p_{i}^TAp_i}$$\frac{p_{i}^Tp_i}{p_{i}^TA^{-1}p_i}$

Context: A is a positive-definite symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, and the solution to the system $Ax=b$ is the unique minimum of the function $f(y) := \frac{1}{2}y^TAy-y^Tb$. We try to find the minimum of $f$ by a "simple iterative procedure" of form $x_{j+1} = x_j + \alpha_j p_j$, where $x_j$ is the current position from which we move in the direction of $p_j$ with step-length of $\alpha_j$. We want $f(x_{j+1}) \leq f(x_j)$.

Given a new direction $p_j$, the "best possible" step-length in that direction can be determined by the minimum of $f$ along the line $x_j + \alpha p_j$. THus, setting the equation $f(x_j + \alpha p_i) = 0$, we determine that 
$\alpha_j = \frac{p_{j}^Tr_j}{p_{j}^TAp_j}$, where $r_j$ is the residual of the $j$th step defined as $r_j = b - Ax_j$. $e_i$ is defined as $e_i := x^* - x_i$ where $x^*$ is the solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of $Ax = b$. (I'm not sure what to make of $e_{i}^T$.)

If more context is needed, I will try to provide more. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If $p_j$ is just the direction and $\alpha_j$ is the length, then it should be true that $\|p_j\| = 1$. If it isn't $1$, your step size would be $\alpha_j\|p_j\|$, not just $\alpha_j$. And if $\|p_j\| = 1$, then $p_i^Tp_i = \|p_i\|^2 = 1$, which simplifies your equation significantly.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for the *steepest descent* method and, for this method, it is very easy to show because we simply have $p_i=r_i$ so (considering that $e_i=A^{-1}r_i)$
$$
\alpha_i\frac{p_i^Tp_i}{e_i^TAe_i}
=
\frac{p_i^Tr_i}{p_i^TAp_i}\frac{p_i^Tp_i}{e_i^TAe_i}
=
\frac{r_i^Tr_i}{r_i^TAr_i}\frac{r_i^Tr_i}{r_i^TA^{-1}r_i}
=
\frac{p_i^Tp_i}{p_i^TAp_i}\frac{p_i^Tp_i}{p_i^TA^{-1}p_i}.
$$

For the *conjugate gradient* method, this is no longer true if $i>0$. Consider, e.g., $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix},\quad b=[1,1]^T, \quad x_0=0.$$
Then, for $i=1$, we have
$$
\alpha_1\frac{p_1^Tp_1}{e_1^TAe_1}
=
\frac{3}{4}
\times
\frac{40}{27}
\neq 
\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{10}{9}
=
\frac{p_1^Tp_1}{p_1^TAp_1}\frac{p_1^Tp_1}{p_1^TA^{-1}p_1}.
$$